# How to modify font without using assets

Tags: android, fonts, download, android-sdcard

```
AssetManager mgr=getAssets();
Typeface tf=Typeface.createFromAsset(mgr, "fonts/cube.ttf");
textView.setTypeface(tf);
```

The method above can modify font of the TextView, but I do not want to do it like this. My idea: The user can download the font on the internet and store it in the sd-card. Then the user can apply the font they just downloaded to the widget. I feel this method can reduce the size of the project. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1.) Download "font.ttf" (Replace with your ttf file name) File to external storage through the internet.

2.) Do this.

```
 Typeface typeface = Typeface.createFromFile(
        new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(), "font.ttf"));
 textView.setTypeface(tf);
```

Comment: thanks,but i don`t know how to download fonts from the internet,can you give me some examples or methods

Comment: You'll need a webserver hosting your fonts or find a host with free downloadable fonts with URL exposed (Check out http://www.fontsquirrel.com/blog/2010/12/the-font-squirrel-api). Then just call the URL to download your font in an asynctask and download the file like mentioned here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3028306/download-a-file-with-android-and-showing-the-progress-in-a-progressdialog

Comment: i'm using eclipse and i have font in particular folder but when i'm trying to set typeface with above solution always get "Native typeface cannot be made" on any device any help?